# Segmentation fault at 'FeedForward()'

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am working on making a simple perception model in C and I had decided that I wanted to have some sort of abstraction using opaque pointers. Code bellow could give more clues to the problem

perceptron.h

```
#ifndef __PERCEPTRON_H__
#define __PERCEPTRON_H__

typedef struct _Perceptron _perceptron;

typedef struct{

//public
    float * input;
    float * weigths;
    int size;
//private 
    void * m_perceptron;

}Perceptron;

Perceptron * InitPerceptron();
void FreePerceptron(Perceptron * instance);
void FeedForward(float input[],float weights[],int size,Perceptron * perceptron);

#endif
```

and this is my perception.c

```
typedef struct _Perceptron{

    float * input;
    int size;

}_perceptron;

static void _FeedForward(float input[],float weights[],int size,_perceptron * p){

    if(p->input == NULL)
        p->input = (float *)calloc(size,sizeof(float));
    
    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
        p->input[i] = input[i] * weights[i];

    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
        printf("%f ",p->input[i]);

}

Perceptron * InitPerceptron(){

    Perceptron * instance = (Perceptron *)malloc(sizeof(Perceptron));
    instance ->m_perceptron = (_perceptron *)malloc(sizeof(_perceptron));
    
    return instance;

}

void FeedForward(float input[],float weights[],int size,Perceptron * perceptron) {

    if(perceptron->input == NULL)
        perceptron->input = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float));
    
    if(perceptron->weigths == NULL)
        perceptron->weigths = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float));

    for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
        perceptron->input[i] = input[i];
        perceptron->weigths[i] = weights[i];
    }

    perceptron->size = size;

    _FeedForward(perceptron->input,perceptron->weigths,perceptron->size,perceptron->m_perceptron);

}


void FreePerceptron(Perceptron * instance){

    free(instance->m_perceptron);
    free(instance);

}
```

and this is my main.c

```
    float input[] = {1,2,3};
    float weights[] = {1,1,1};

    Perceptron * perceptron = InitPerceptron();
    FeedForward(input,weights,3,perceptron);
    FreePerceptron(perceptron);

    return 0;
```

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: E:\repos\NeuralNetwork\bin\neuralnetwork.exe
[New Thread 14564.0x49c4]
[New Thread 14564.0x3a44]

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004017b4 in FeedForward ()
(gdb)
```

This is the error I am getting

My initial guess is that maybe I am accessing pointers perception and _perceptron as NULL pointers, so I tried removing the FeedForward function and it seems to work just fine. My next guess is that the inputs probably are given in a wrong way, but that does not seem likely.What could be the cause for the segmentation fault. Could it be in the main function itself our is it something related to the use of malloc to the float pointers or is the use of my opaque pointers wrong ?

Comment: Is this a C++ question?

Comment: GDB will tell you what is wrong, no need to guess. I would suggest to also use sanitizers, they can spot these mistakes - memory,address,undefined,leak, and thread. Can be enabled with `-fsanitize` flag in GCC and Clang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values stored here are uninitialized at the moment of comparison:

```
if(perceptron->input == NULL)
```

and

```
if(perceptron->weigths == NULL)
```

and

```
if(p->input == NULL)
```

Which means that there may be no memory allocated for these pointers. Set these explicitly to`NULL` to solve the problem.

Side note: It is "weights", not "weigths".